# php Download an image to put it in several different folders

Tags: php, image, checkbox, file-upload, copy

Well, my request is that each checked check box sends the chosen image, but I don't know of any other way than the "move_uploaded_file". Maybe it is only my code that is needed or simply my request cannot work. I thought of an option that copies the image and sends it to the requested folders. Thank you for reading my question.

PHP

```
   // Create database connection
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");
    // Initialize message variable
    $msg = "";

    // If upload button is clicked ...
    if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        // Get image name
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        //GET image nom
        $image_nom = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_nom']);
        // Get text
        $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);
        // image file directory
        if (isset($_POST['combat'])) {
            $target = "combat/images/".basename($image);
        
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                    $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
            }else{
                    $msg = "Failed to upload image";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_nom, image_text) VALUES ('$image', '$image_nom', '$image_text')";
        // execute query
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['personnage'])) {
            $targetp = "search/personnages/".basename($image);
        
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $targetp)) {
                    $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
            }else{
                    $msg = "Failed to upload image";
            }
            $sql = "INSERT INTO personnage (image_personnage, image_nom_personnage, image_text_personnage) VALUES ('$image', '$image_nom', '$image_text')";
        // execute query
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        }
```

AND HTML

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="combat" name="combat">
  <label for="combat">Combat</label></br>

  <input type="checkbox" id="personnage" name="personnage">
  <label for="personnage">Personnage</label></form>
```

Comment: Adjust `$target` to where you want to move the uploaded image. Not sure I follow why what you are showing is not putting them in two different location.

Comment: it seems that when the image is downloaded the first checkbox moves it and then the second checkbox does not find the image, which is normal but is there a solution

Comment: Oh I see, you want the *same* image in *two places*.

Comment: yes the checkbox sends the place instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move_uploaded_file() just move the uploaded file and you can use it one time ,but you can use copy() function to copy the files as many times you want like this example

```
move_uploaded_file($uploaded, $destination);
copy($destination, $destination2);
```

but your code have a major security issue because you allow every type of files to upload which can make anyone to hack your website .

**I suggest to you :**

1. add `accept='image/*'` to `input type='file'` in your html.
2. check file extension and MIME Type by this code :

`$ext=explode(".",$_FILES['image']['name'][$i]);`

`$ext=strtolower($ext[1]);`

```
if ((($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'][$i] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES['image']['size'][$i] < 5000000)
&& in_array($ext,array("gif","jpeg","jpg","png"))){}
```

3. then create image from the temp file :

   `switch ($ext){`
   `case 'jpg':$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);break;`
   `case 'jpeg':$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);break;`
   `case 'png':$image=imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);break;`
   `case 'gif':$image=imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);break;`
   `}`
4. use `imagejpeg($image,$path,75)` or `imagepng($image,$path,8)` to create the image and save it in the path you can use these two function as much as you want and don't forget to use `imagedestroy($image)` when you finish .

if you need anything else tell me .

EDIT : adding new code

```php
if($_FILES['image']['name']!=''){
$ext=explode(".",$_FILES['image']['name']);
$ext=strtolower($ext[1]);

if ((($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES['image']['type'] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 12000000)
&& in_array($ext,array("gif","jpeg","jpg","png"))){

$is_jpg=true;$ex='jpg';

switch ($ext){
case 'jpg':$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);break;
case 'jpeg':$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);break;
case 'png':$image=imagecreatefrompng($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);$ex='png';$is_jpg=false;break;
case 'gif':$image=imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);$ex='gif';$is_jpg=false;break;
default:$image=imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);break;
}

//set random name for img to avoid duplicate name
$img_name='upload_'.mb_substr(md5($_FILES['image']['name'].rand(0,50)),0,rand(5,10)).'.'.$ex;

$width=imagesx($image);$height=imagesy($image);

//if image jpg
if($is_jpg){
//change to your upload path
isset($_POST['combat']){imagejpeg($image,'combat/images/'.$img_name,80);}
isset($_POST['personnage']){imagejpeg($image,'search/personnages/'.$img_name,80);}

imagedestroy($image);
}

// if image png or gif to save alpha . if gif will not be animated
else{

$bg = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagesavealpha($bg, TRUE);
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocatealpha($bg, 0, 0, 0,127));
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0,$width, $height);
imagedestroy($image);
isset($_POST['combat']){imagepng($bg,'combat/images/'.$img_name,8);}
isset($_POST['personnage']){imagepng($bg,'search/personnages/'.$img_name,8);}
imagedestroy($bg);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will use the code you show me and I will adjust

Comment: I tested your code but I would like to have information on "imagejpeg ($ image, $ path, 75) or imagepng ($ image, $ path, 8)", then I must continue to use move_uploaded_file in each check box ?

Comment: don't use move_uploaded_file because imagejpeg() or  imagepng() make a new image in the path. check here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: Annoying there is no "imagecreatefromjpg" only "imagecreatefromjpeg"

Comment: yeah if you see my answer you see imagecreatefromjpeg for both jpg and jpeg these same file types no problem

Comment: Ok but if I use your code by adapting it with mine the variable "$ i" is not defined.          

Sorry to ask but I would really like my checkbox system to work
Another error is this "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagejpg () in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ siteweb \ game \ index.php: 34 Stack trace: # 0 {main} thrown in", this error only marks "imagejpg ()"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry you don't need [$i] , imagejpg() wrong syntax use imagejpeg() as the link I put it above

Comment: I changed your code, I manage to get an unnamed image in a folder but after to move the image I can't. Also the variable "$ image" cannot be used. But the file which has no name it in any form windows requires software to open it, I don't understand

Comment: i edit my answer and add code to upload image try it

Comment: Thank you very much but unfortunately the variable "$ i" is not defined

Comment: i'm sorry check it now i remove $i

Comment: Everything works well the image moves to the right place but when two checkboxes are checked the image moves to the last requested folder location. I suppose I have to modify the variable "$ path" or rename it otherwise?